# Mathematica cannot compile complex-valued interpolated PDE coefficients? (NDSolve, Finite Elements)

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier, fixed in 11.3 or earlier.**

---

The following PDE

```
pde = I Cos[x y] D[u[x, y], x] + Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
```

Is happily solved by

```
NDSolve[{pde, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Cos[x y], True]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,
   1}]
```

However, if I set up the advection coefficient using interpolation, things go askew:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
R = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[R]; 
coords = mesh["Coordinates"]; 
CosA = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
   Table[{xi, yi} = coords[[i]]; 
    Cos[xi yi], {i, 1, Length[coords]}]];
pde = I CosA[x, y] D[u[x, y], x] + Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
NDSolve[{pde, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Cos[x y], True]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,
   1}]
```

Mathematica issues the complaint CompiledFunction::cfex --

> CompiledFunction: Could not complete external evaluation at
>   instruction 10; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

Though the answer is ultimately obtained, the behavior is curious to me.  (Also, I need the speedup that comes with compiling.)

Note that the problem is not due to interpolation alone, e.g. one can drop the `I`,

```
pde = CosA[x, y] D[u[x, y], x] + Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
```

and compilation works.  The issue, as far as I can tell, involves the special  imaginary-interpolated combination.  Two questions:

1. Why this behavior?
2. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with _Mathematica_ version 12.0. Please restart you kernel. Maybe there was some definition lingering around in some symbol.

Comment: What version are you using? This works fine in 11.3 and 12.0.

Comment: @user21 and Henrick Shumacher, I'm using 11.1.1.0.  I'll upgrade and report back.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks for the code edit.

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this?

Comment: @user21 the upgrade process takes a bit of time, the way things are set up with licensing at my institute.  Nearly there....

Comment: @user21, I am using version 12.0 now and the problem is fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. So it's a bug that was fixed before 11.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by upgrading to Mathematica 12.0.